# publishing shotwell albums to Flickr / Picasa

Tags: sharing, photo-management, shotwell, metadata

I'd like to ask two questions relating to Shotwell if I may.

Firstly: How do I alter the meta-data of the pics imported to Shotwell? I have some showing up as having been taken in 2095 and so on.

Secondly, I'd like to upload my pictures to either Flickr / Picasa. Ideally I'd like to manage all the pics from Shotwell and just sync with the web service as pics are added, changed etc. Which, if either, service would let me do this?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu, this site works better when you ask one question per post. Please edit your post to ask one question, and then just ask another one for your second question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For the first one select the photo(s) then Photo from the menus and then Adjust Date And Time. Also select Modify Original File in the pop-up.

Comment: That sorts out point #1.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the second point: no, at this time you cannot to a "sync" with these services service.  In other words, you can publish photos to Flickr or Picasa, but you can't automatically get photos into Shotwell when you add them to Flickr or Picasa.

I agree that this would be a fantastic feature, and we do have a ticket for doing this, but it would be a pretty major change and at this point I don't think we've even looked into whether or not any of the online photo sites have a way to do this in their APIs.

Ticket is here: http://trac.yorba.org/ticket/2676

Comment: I actually wanted the reverse of this - for changes in Shotwell (creating managing albums/pics etc) to be reflected on my Picasa account. So basically - my Shotwell is used to control everything that is also online.

Comment: Ah, ok.  No, that's not exactly doable.  You have to publish photos manually, and Shotwell doesn't remember what was published before.  If it were implemented, would this be helpful to you? http://trac.yorba.org/ticket/2797

Comment: It would absolutely be useful to have shotwell track and update downstream web publishing platforms. And it is very important to keep description metadata with photos, so I'd love it if you could at least send the title and description to e.g. picasa / google plus when you publish an album. That is still not happening with shotwell 0.18.0 in Ubuntu Trusty despite pleas from places like the Library of Congress, who worry that our digital heritage is being forgotten: http://blogs.loc.gov/digitalpreservation/2011/10/mission-possible-an-easy-way-to-add-descriptions-to-digital-photos/

Comment: @nealmcb Shotwell was created by the Yorba Foundation, which is now defunct [due to an IRS policy change](http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2014/07/irs-policy-that-targeted-tea-party-groups-also-aimed-at-open-source-projects/).  (Full disclosure: I'm a former Yorba employee.)  Since Shotwell is now an unmaintained project, I wouldn't count on bugfixes -- let alone entire new features.